# Rest API to submit PyFlink job

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

Is there any way to submit a PyFlink job to a cluster using Rest API?
I check out this link https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/ops/rest_api/ but did not find any API related to python files.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible at the moment. I also don't see a feature request for this in the Flink Jira tickets, but you can create one of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is a stale, open PR to add this to the REST API: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/8532
...though it hasn't had activity recently.